# Webcallout through proxy

Tags: webservices, rest

We have a webservice they is being moved to a proxy.  It works when calling it by normal means (using Advanced REST Client plugin), but when calling from Salesforce we get an 'Unable to Tunnel through Proxy' error.  Any ideas to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third party system that you are trying to make callout block salesforce as best practice .

Every enterprise organisation for security purpose they have firewall and Proxy .

You can read more on proxy from below link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

So you may need to ask your third party that you are integrating with to whitelist salesforce so that request from salesforce don't get blocked .You will need to provide salesforce IP to them in order for them to facilitate this request

Please refer below document link to get salesforce IP .Whitelisting them by your third party will resove your issue .

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003652